# How to equal an input with a list element?

Tags: python, list, input

​Why do I keep getting False even if the input was in the list?

```
My_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
letter = input("enter a letter").lower
letter = str(letter)
if letter in My_list:
     print(True)
else:
     print(False)
```

Comment: `lower` is a method. You need to call it like `"A".lower()` Also, `letter = str(letter)` is unnecessary; it's already a string.

Answer (score 0):

You miss brackets after `.lower()`.
Like this, this line simple doesn't work, and as a result you have False return.